# No sound on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, alsa

I have been working on the sound for about 3 days now with no success.

I have tried all the information about configuring sound for 16.04 on here but nothing works.

I am a bit disappointed with Ubuntu now as I first installed 16.04 over 2 years ago and had the same problems.

Basically I am tring to get the Epson printer and the sound to work and it seems that the problem is still not fixed.

I tried uninstalling pulse and ALSA and then reinstalling ALSA. The terminal output said `broken packages`.

I had a look at alsamixer, and it says `This device does not have any capture controls.`

I have tried all the other scripts on here but no luck on configuring it correctly. What should I do?

Comment: Please post `lshw -C sound` output at your question. To repair broken packages, do `sudo apt install -f`. If successfully, `sudo apt install --reinstall alsa pulseaudio`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Audio`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.